# autofetch date in slack workflow

Tags: slack

I am creating a simple workflow(No coding yet) with a scheduled timer that will send a message in a Slack channel every day at 5 AM UTC. I want the Message to auto picks up the date while sending the message. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can not do so without coding an implementation.

When setting up messages as a workflow step using the basic slack-provided option, the only variables you can insert in the message are references to the channel where the workflow is being executed and to the user executing the workflow.

Coding up a workflow step is not particularly challenging though, so take a look at the slack documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/workflow-builder-steps) for a guide on how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Slack has added some more options for dates in their messages. There is now a "Time when workflow started" variable which I think will accomplish what you're looking for.

[image: Image showing the variable picker in the Slack workflow builder]

There are additional options to add dates depending on the trigger/previous steps in your workflows as shown here:

[image: Second image showing more option in the Workflow builder variable picker]